# How to allow methods within my engine to be edited , without editing its Java class (or the equivalent)

Tags: java, android

I'm currently working on a UI Engine called PlaneUI

To give you a basic idea, it's a touch UI system where the entire screen is made up of "Planes", which can show content, as well as be used as buttons. (Additional Info Below)

> When the user is not interacting with the screen, he/she sees a continuous surface of content (which is actually made up of Planes), but when the user touches a Plane, he/she can differentiate the individual Plane, and see it being pressed down like a button. The point of the system is to eliminate the need for clunky on-screen buttons and allow a very elegant design whilst maintaining rich touch feedback. Screen transitions are shown using these Planes as well.

To make development implementing this system feasible and make it open to other developers, I made a class called PlaneView which extends SurfaceView which internally handles all of the Plane management. The only thing that needs to be added by the developer using this engine is the content to be drawn on each Plane, and what happens when these Planes are pressed, released etc.

Currently, methods within PlaneView, such as **draw, press, release, etc.** are called when a Plane is drawing its content, gets pressed, released etc. However, in this case, developers need to go into the PlaneView class and add code into the declaration of these methods, such as the content to draw, and actions to be taken when pressed, released etc.

Is there any Java programming mechanism(?) I can use so that developers can define these things within their own classes?

I apologize about the excessive use of abstract language. I'll take any advise about terminology or my possible misconceptions about the Java language (I've been programming with GML on Game Maker Studio, and started Java only recently)

Comment: This sounds like you created a framework ... that doesn't work as framework. The point is: when other people are be using your `PlaneView` class, then they should NOT need to change anything in your class `PlainView`. `PlainView` should know any items added to it; and all of its methods should deal with these items. Otherwise, your whole framework is useless. To be more precise: any component that can be added to such a plane must contain all the information for "draw", "press", etc.

Comment: @EddyG Actually, that's kind of  the reason I asked this question. The problem is, the 'items' that need to be added into this system includes everything that needs to be drawn into the app that implements this system. I don't plan on making a framework(?) that handles drawing images, shapes, text,  etc. (basically a whole other version of Android canvas). What I was hoping was that there could be a way that the PlaneView class can reach the draw code written by the developer in a separate class. If you consider that kind of system 'useless', I'll consider looking for other methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make PlaneView an abstract class that has abstract methods onDraw, onPress etc. Developers using PlaneView would have to extend PlaneView and implement the relevant methods. Make sure to be careful with what is private, what is protected and what is public within PlaneView.

```
public abstract class PlaneView {

    protected abstract void onDraw();

    // Similarly for the other methods ...
```

Comment: But then I would suggest different naming: aren't we talking about items that are added to a plane?

Comment: I know it says to avoid comments like "thanks", but this is just the perfect advice!

Comment: @EddyG Maybe I should have been a bit more elaborate in my explanation. PlaneView does not draw items previously added to Planes. It simple handles the user input and Plane transitions to provide the developer using PlaneView with the information they need to know. These include: When which Plane has been pressed or released, which Planes are currently shown on the screen and where, the order in which Planes should be drawn to get the correct spacial effect etc. The only drawing that PlaneView does is visual effects to show that a Plane has been pressed, is in transition etc.